# Нужна помощь по Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Есть кусок кода который удаляет и создает папку Updates.
Помогите, как реализовать - если папка пустая, то чекбокс неактивен и  надпись "Очистить папку Updates(файлы отсутствуют)"
Если в ней есть файлы чекбокс активен и надпись "Очистить папку Updates, освободив место на диске ....(kb, mb, gb)"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 function BackupCheck_5(): Boolean.
    begin
      If DeleteUpdatesCheckBox.Checked then
    begin
      DelTree(ExpandConstant('{app}\Updates'), True, True, True);
      CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{app}\Updates'));
    end;
    end;
```

Comment: Думаю, нужно начать с функции для подсчета общего размера файлов в папке Updates. А дальше, в зависимости от полученного значения изменять Caption и активность чекбокса.

Comment: Можете пример привести.

Comment: Пример чего вы хотите увидеть? Список доступных функций для работы с файлами есть в справке http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions в разделе _File System functions_. Задайте конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Как создать функцию для подсчета общего размера файлов в папке Updates.и от полученного значения изменять Caption и активность чекбокса. Пример не напишите? Это конкретный вопрос?

Comment: Пример напишу. Добавьте в вопрос кусок кода, который создает страничку с этим чекбоксом.

Answer (score 0):

Функция для получения размера папки Updates и всех вложенных папок:

```
function GetFolderSize(const FolderPath: string): Int64;
var
  SearchPattern: string;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  Result := 0;
  SearchPattern := FolderPath + '\*' 
  if FindFirst(FolderPath, FindRec) then
  try
    repeat
      if (FindRec.Name <> '..') and (FindRec.Name <> '.') then  // папка верхнего уровня и текущая папка нам не нужны
      begin
        if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0 then
          Result := Result + (FindRec.SizeHigh shl 32) + FindRec.SizeLow // прибавим размер найденного файла к общему размеру
        else
          Result := Result + GetFolderSize(FindRec.Name); // подсчет размера вложенной папки
      end;
    until not FindNext(FindRec);
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

function GetUpdatesSize(): Int64;
begin
  Result := GetFolderSize(ExpandConstant('{app}\Updates'));
end;
```

Comment: Ругается unknown type "int64"

Comment: Обновите версию InnoSetup. На "Inno Setup Compiler version 5.5.9 (u)" скрипт с этими функциями компилится без вопросов. Как вариант, можно попробовать заменить `Int64` на `Integer` и убрать `+ (FindRec.SizeHigh shl 32)`, если вы уверены, что ваша папка `Updates` **ни при каких обстоятельствах и никогда** не будет размером более 2 ГБ.